# How to get absolute A1 Notation in Google Sheet Range by Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

We can use .getA1Notation() to get Notation of a  cell Range, for example D3
Could you guys please advise any idea of how to get absolute Notation for a Range, for example $D$3 ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that `getA1Notation()` cannot directly return the a1Notation like `$D$3`. So, in your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

const a1Notation1a = sheet.getRange(3, 4).getA1Notation();
const a1Notation1b = sheet.getRange(3, 4).getA1Notation().replace(/([A-Z]+)/g, "$$$1$$");
console.log(a1Notation1a) // D3
console.log(a1Notation1b) // $D$3

const a1Notation2a = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 2, 2).getA1Notation();
const a1Notation2b = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 2, 2).getA1Notation().replace(/([A-Z]+)/g, "$$$1$$");
console.log(a1Notation2a) // A1:B2
console.log(a1Notation2b) // $A$1:$B$2
```

#### References:

- [getA1Notation()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#geta1notation)
- [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)